# Tying accountID to ContactID in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We use person accounts in SF CRM. This is integrated with other systems using the accountID as identifier for our customers. We are integrating Marketing Cloud with an orchestration service we have that can pass us the SF accountID as the client identifier. Can we use this to map to the contactID in Marketing Cloud in order to send an email? Or do we need this outside service to pass the contactID?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using person accounts, you should use `PersonContactId` as the subscriber key.

Use the [Marketing Cloud Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221686&type=2&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to bring the data over from Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you for responding. We are using the connector, but also already have an internal application that receives email triggers from source systems, gathers data, decisions and then sends data needed to deliver an email. In this case, we are just using marketing cloud to deliver the email (SF and MC are brand new to our ecosystem so we are implementing in small chunks).This internal application can grab the SF AccountId, so I am just wondering if we can use this in MC or if it is better for this system to also have access to the ContactId. Let me know if this makes sense